# Adding drag and drop functionality to metro style app buttons with C# and XAML

Tags: xaml, drag-and-drop, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I'm trying to implement a sort of drag functionality into my app. As a simplistic example imagine I have a 2x2 square of buttons, so four buttons total. Clicking a button will perform some other functionality however I want when they hold and drag one of these buttons for it to do something else (ideally if you drag one button and drop it while in the space of another button the two buttons will swap places, as long as I can get dragging and dropping working the swap should be easy).

I've done some research and followed a few tutorials but seemed to get errors at one step or another with all of those. It seems ListViews and GridViews have some drag and drop functionality in them already , but I had trouble properly arranging my buttons (there are many more than four and they are in very specific positions, like a diagram) inside these views, let alone getting drag and drop working with them.

How would I go about doing this? Ideally I could just tag these buttons as draggable, and then on a drag-drop event check for a drop position, then if the position is valid perform a swap method. I just can't seem to figure out how to make them draggable or how to have an event that checks a drop position.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Easy peasy, create a custom control that looks the way you want it to, set ManipulationMode to TranslateX|TranslateY, handle manipulation delta events to update positioning with something like a Canvas or TranslateTransform and when manipulation completes - either make it click or animate to the new position. From my experience - getting any other manipulations to work with a regular Button class just isn't working and since a button is a really simple control - it is easier to create your own than try to extend the existing one in such cases.

Comment: Sorry I can only work on this project at specific times so it might take me awhile to see answers, and I'm not the most experienced coder.
So what you're saying is to create a usercontrol and then write code that checks how far an item has been dragged on an X and Y axis, after that based on the X and Y position it was dropped in I can write code to do the swaps?
Would it not be visually dragging but rather just be working based on a starting and ending X and Y position? I've never made a usercontrol before so I'm not really sure what manipulation mode would do or manipulation delta events.